# minimatch failed to match the string and regexp

Tags: regex, minimatch

I wanted to construct a regexp that won't match any elements in a given array(each element is a string). For example, if the given array is `['a','b']`, then the regexp will match any string except for `'a'` and `'b'`. So I wrote a function like this:

```js
const generateRegex = array => {
  const escapedStrings = array.map(s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'))
  const regex = `^(?!.*(?:${escapedStrings.join('|')})).*$`
  return regex
}
```

And it worked well. For example:

```js
const generateRegex = array => {
  const escapedStrings = array.map(s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'))
  const regex = `^(?!.*(?:${escapedStrings.join('|')})).*$`
  return regex
}
const regExp = generateRegex(['a','b'])
console.log(new RegExp(regExp).test('a'))   // false
console.log(new RegExp(regExp).test('b'))   // false
console.log(new RegExp(regExp).test('c'))   // true
```

For some reason, I had to use minimatch to do things what `new RegExp().test()` does. So I wrote the code like this:

```js
const minimatch = require("minimatch");
const generateRegex = array => {
  const escapedStrings = array.map(s => s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'))
  const regex = `^(?!.*(?:${escapedStrings.join('|')})).*$`
  return regex
}
const regExp = generateRegex(['a','b'])
console.log(minimatch('a',regExp))   // false
console.log(minimatch('b',regExp))   // false
console.log(minimatch('c',regExp))   // false
```

As you can see, all the logs were `false`. This was strange since the string `c` exactly matched the `regExp`.

Comment: If you are talking about [this minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch), it apparently expects a glob expression as second parameter, not a regex. It seems to convert constructs like `(a|b)` to javascript regular expressions internally.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid building compound expressions and would just map all strings to RegExp tests, if it's an option; something like: `['a', 'b'].map(s => new RegExp(s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')).test('foobar'))` which would get you `[true, true]`.